# Crear password concatenando dos campos de la DB mysql. con PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo un input de un form, el cual recibe una variable $id_orden, que al introducir un $id_orden existente= Arroja como resultado la descarga de un pdf con sus respectivos datos.

el id_orden funciona como una password para poder descargar.

Lo que necesito hacer es que pueda ingresar en el input, dos datos para poder acceder a ese archivo pdf.

BASE DE DATOS

id_orden----- Idenificacion

125 ------------- AN154

145--------------AJ147

---

Seria que para introducir en el input y que pueda arrojar el archivo pdf
si o si hubiera que introducir estos dos valores combinados
125AN154

$id_orden=$_POST['id_orden'];

$productos ="SELECT serie,tarjeta,cable_hdmi,cable_av,fuente,control_1,id_orden FROM express WHERE id_orden = '$id_orden'";

tendria que agregar la variable $identificacion=$_POST['id_orden']=> para recibir los datos por ahi, pero necesitaria concatenar en mi consulta estos dos campos id_orden + identificacion para que la consulta sea verdadera y arroje el pdf. Que al buscar en el WHERE sea por id_orden + identificacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si entendi... tu necesitas que al ingresar en el formulario en 2 campos... tengas que ingresar algo asi:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1">
    <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2">
</form>
```

podrias usar algo asi como esto, te doy varias ideas:

recoger los 2 input y hacerlos variables

```
$search_term = $input1 . " " .$input2;
```

acá ya lo envias concatenado en la funcion search_term

```
$productos ="SELECT serie,tarjeta,cable_hdmi,cable_av,fuente,control_1,id_orden FROM express WHERE id_orden = '$search_term'";
```

por otro lado podes enviarlo de la misma manera por separado y concatenarlo en el mysql:

haciendo un get del input1 y del intput2 transformarlos en variable y enviarlos al mysql de la siguiente manera... con eso los concatenas (donde puse los *** es por ejemplo util poner un espacio en blanco para buscar nombres y apellidos por ejemplo y que al buscarlos ponga un espacio entre ambos, sino dejalo sin nada elimina los asteriscos)

```
$productos ="SELECT serie,tarjeta,cable_hdmi,cable_av,fuente,control_1,id_orden FROM express WHERE concat_ws('***',input1,input2) 
like '%$search_term%' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser también:

```
$id_orden = $_POST['id_orden'].$_POST['identificacion'];

$productos ="SELECT serie, tarjeta, cable_hdmi, cable_av, fuente,control_1, id_orden 
FROM express 
WHERE id_orden = '$id_orden'";
```

Los concatena los dos post.